# How does Safari's Reader work and when does it show up?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, safari-5

[Safari's Reader feature](http://www.apple.com/safari/features.html#browsing) is a cool little app that displays a web page as a newspaper article --- without all the distracting sidebars, comments, and ads. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't, and I'm wondering how "it knows when to show up." On my personal website, one of the pages has this option. You can click the `Reader` button in the URL bar and it is displayed beautifully like a page in an iBook. However, none of my other web pages (on the same site) do this. I thought it had something to do with the `<article>` tag, but I removed that and it still works. **Anyone know how this app works?**

Also, does anyone know of any [Chrome extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/home) that are just like this? [Google Reader](http://www.google.com/reader/) is not the same thing.

PS: From the cited Apple website:

> **Safari Reader**
>
> As you browse the web, Safari detects if you are on a web page with an article. Click the Reader button that appears in the Smart Address Field and an elegant view of the article appears — without any distracting content.

Not much help, is it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Safari's Reader makes use of [Readability](http://www.readability.com/).

> Readability turns any web page into a clean view for reading now or later on your computer, smartphone, or tablet.

---

There's this [nice article](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/safari-reader) about how Safari's Reader detects the text, you should consider reading.

> It looks like that Safari Reader will detect a `<div>` or block level element that contains a header element (`<h1>` to `<h6>`), followed by a certain amount of text. The reader badge will appear when the content text (not including the header) is more than 2,000 characters.

---

There's a Readability extension for Chrome which you can get from [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oknpjjbmpnndlpmnhmekjpocelpnlfdi).

Comment: Safari Reader can also detect multi-page articles and download all papges.

Comment: Safari uses Readability? I think it uses its own implementation.

Comment: I don't think safari uses this exactly, as I have used reader on articles that were definitely less than 2000 words

Comment: This answer was from 6 years ago and as far as I can tell from current usage Safari definitely has its own implementations and it's not restricted to <div>, <h1>, etc or the the 2000 character minimum size.

Answer (score 7):

You can take a look at its [source code](http://blog.manbolo.com/2013/03/18/safari-reader.js)

Method how to obtain it [is here](http://blog.manbolo.com/2013/03/18/safari-reader-source-code)

Comment: How can you use that script in your own website

Answer (score 2):

Evernote offers a similar plugin for Chrome called [Clearly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clearly/iooicodkiihhpojmmeghjclgihfjdjhj?hl=en) that also integrates with an Evernote Notebook if you use that system.

https://evernote.com/clearly/

There is also a Clearly plugin for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/clearly/).

Installing the plugin gives you a toolbar button next to the address bar that you click to view a "clean" version of the page and which includes a few GUI tweaks for low light or background color change if beige offends your sensibilities, as well as a button to copy the cleared page to an Evernote Notebook.